# Threads communication Java

Tags: java, multithreading, interruptions

I have a problem dealing with thread communication in java. I am doing a project that will connect people to 3 different Elevators (depending on the floor they want to go) that have a capacity limit. The thing is I have three difficulties.

1. My code is Consumer-Producer problem based, and I don't know how to change it so the elevator doesn't wait for it to be full, but starts after time by itself.
2. Another one is that the program stops before completing the loops. (no idea why).
3. If i try to check if the elevator hasn't been chosen (by geting the capacity) and not display the info of it being back at floor 0, the program doesn't work.

My code: (Classes of elevator 2 and 3 and their buffers are identical)

```
public class Proba { //test class
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pojemnik c = new Pojemnik();
        Pojemnik1 d = new Pojemnik1();
        Pojemnik2 e = new Pojemnik2();
        Winda p1 = new Winda(c, 1);
        Winda1 p2 = new Winda1(d, 2);
        Winda2 p3 = new Winda2(e, 3);
        Osoba c1 = new Osoba(c, d, e, 1);
        p1.start(); 
        p2.start();
        p3.start();
        c1.start();
    }
}

class Osoba extends Thread  //person class
{
    private Pojemnik pojemnik;
    private Pojemnik1 pojemnik1;
    private Pojemnik2 pojemnik2;
    private int number;
    public Osoba(Pojemnik c, Pojemnik1 d, Pojemnik2 e, int number) {
        pojemnik = c;
        pojemnik1 = d;
        pojemnik2 = e;
        this.number = number;
    }
    public void run() {
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
            {
                int k=0;
                while (k==0){ //i dont; want floor 0
                k = -2 + (int)(Math.random()*7);} //choosing floor
                int h;

                if(k>-3&&k<1){ //decision which elevator
                    value = pojemnik.get(); // getting possible capacity
                    if(value>0){
                        pojemnik.put(value-1);} //lowering capacity
                    h=5-value; // how many people are already in 
                    System.out.println("Ktos wsiadl do windy #1" 
                            //+ this.number
                            + " jest w niej " + h + " osob i wybrano pietro nr " + k);
                } 
                if(k>-1&&k<4){
                    value = pojemnik1.get();
                    if(value>0){
                        pojemnik1.put(value-1);}
                    h=5-value;
                    System.out.println("Ktos wsiadl do windy #2" 
                            //+ this.number
                            + " jest w niej " + h + " osob i wybrano pietro nr " + k);
                }
                if(k>3&&k<8){
                    value = pojemnik2.get();
                    if(value>0){
                        pojemnik1.put(value-1);}
                    h=5-value;
                    System.out.println("Ktos wsiadl do windy #3" 
                            //+ this.number
                            + " jest w niej " + h + " osob i wybrano pietro nr " + k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//import java.util.*;
//import java.lang.*;
class Pojemnik  //buffor class
{
    private int contents;
    private boolean available = false;
    public synchronized int get() {
        while (available == false) {
            try {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        available = false;
        notifyAll();
        return contents;
    }
    public synchronized void put(int value) {
        while (available == true) {
            try {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { 
            } 
        }
        contents = value;
        if(value>5){ //way to never get too high capacity
            contents=5;
        }
        available = true;
        notifyAll();
    }
}

// import java.lang.*;   // elevator class
class Winda extends Thread {
    private Pojemnik pojemnik; //bufor
    private int number;

    public Winda(Pojemnik c, int number) {
        pojemnik = c;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //pojemnik.get();
            pojemnik.put(5);    // the elevator is empty 5 people can go in
            System.out.println("Winda #" + this.number
                    + " jest na poziomie 0 "); //info that elevator is on floor 0
            try {
                sleep((int)(Math.random() * 100));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not talking about a real elevator, right?

Comment: I wonder why newbies always tackle the more trickier parts of the language first. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: it would be much easier for others to read if the code was written in english, with variables and classes names describing what they do.

Comment: @I.K. I suspect they just want to learn interesting parts first. Using RPG language, they are here for raid-boss, not minions :)

Comment: Of course not, that would definietly be a disaster :D

Comment: I can translate them if you want. And as far the language is concerned don;t blame me. blame educational system at my university.

Comment: @I.K. its what they're told to do in school ... teachers & professors all over the world get bored after a few decades so they start to overstrain pupils and basically ... create infinite learning barriers. Thats one of the reasons for me hating every school, every college on this planet. Incompetent teachers are a major danger to society.

Comment: @specializt to be exact this is what we are told to do after 8 hours of classes about java and multithreading.

Comment: I figured out how to deal with problem 1 and 2. Now it's only down to problem 3.

Comment: @Richard exactly. You should consider switching class or teacher (if that is possible), apparently he is incompetent. Im sorry if you like him but ... its kinda obvious.